# botão envia value de campo input hidden

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, button

Estou com um problema quanto ao uso de um botão específico no projeto. Vou explicar: Tenho uma janela aberta pelo comando window.open, então nessa janela aberta tenho um botão que pega o valor de dois campos input hidden no qual está em while no banco de dados. Ao clicar nele, tem uma função onde envia o valor desse campo hidden para outro input da página em que executa o window.open (para simplificar, a página x.php abre via window.open a página y.php, então na página y.php tem um botão que envia um valor retornado do banco de dados para o campo input no x.php).

Aí que começa o problema, ao clicar eu até consigo enviar de um input ao outro, só que apenas o primeiro registro listado do banco de dados, os outros não enviam.

Segue a parte do y.php onde faz essa função:

Esse são os campos hidden:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM equipamentos WHERE marker_id LIKE '$id'";


 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

  <td>".$row['id']."</td>
  <td>".$row['nome']."</td>

<td style=\"text-align:center;\">".$row['lat']."></td>
<td style=\"text-align:center;\">".$row['lng']."</td>
<td style=\"text-align:center;\">
  <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"latMap\" id=\"latMap\" value ='".$row['lat'] ."'></input>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"lngMap\" id=\"lngMap\" value ='". $row['lng'] ."'></input>";
</td>
```

Então tenho o botão para enviar:

```
<button type=\"button\" id=\"btnLocalizar\" name=\"btnLocalizar\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-primary\">
                            <i class=\"fas fa-map-marker-alt\"></i></button>
```

E o script para enviar:

```
    <script>
  var input1 = document.getElementById('latMap').value;
  var input2 = document.getElementById('lngMap').value;

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnLocalizar').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var input_value = $('#latMap').val();
      $(window.opener.document)

        .find('#latMap')
        .val(input_value)
    });
  });
  </script>
```

O único problema é só conseguir enviar o primeiro registro, se alguém souber como fazer para pegar todos os registros listados pela query do banco de dados, seria de grande ajuda.

Comment: No y.php vc tem um while e que enviar todos os input hidden #latMap para um input na página x.php? Tudo num input só na página x.php?

Comment: Assim, tenho dois campos inputs na página x, e tenho dois input hidden na página y, só que esse input hidden só envia o value do primeiro registro listado da query. Eu queria que quando eu clicasse no botão do segundo registro (ex: registro 1 - brntwp; registro 2 - dvd) ele substituiisse o valor que tava naquele campo input lá do x, e conforme iria clicando no botões ao lado dos registros, trocaria lá nos dois inputs do x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há alguns problemas no código, como duplicidade de `id`s. O botão da janela vai sempre enviar o primeiro `id` que encontrar. Ou você remove os `id`s ou coloque uma variável que diferencie os `id`s, como, por exemplo, uma variável de incremento no `while`:

```
$x = 0;
while(){
   ...
   <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"latMap\" id=\"latMap".$x."\" value ='".$row['lat'] ."'></input>
   <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"lngMap\" id=\"lngMap".$x."\" value ='". $row['lng'] ."'></input>";
   ...
   $x++;
}
```

> Se estava usando os `id`s apenas para capturar os elementos, você não
>   irá precisar deles e pode removê-los. A mesma coisa com o `name` e `id` dos botões dentro do `while`.

Outra coisa são estas duas linhas:

```
var input1 = document.getElementById('latMap').value;
var input2 = document.getElementById('lngMap').value;
```

Não devem servir para nada, então pode removê-las também.

O `e.preventDefault();` também não tem serventia, já que os `button`s são de *cliques* e não de *submit*. Pode remover essa linha também.

Como os botões estão na mesma linha da tabela que os `input`, você pode pegar o evento *click* pela classe `.btn`, capturando o valor do `input hidden` pelo `name`. Então seu código de envio dos valores ficaria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn').click(function(){
      var linha = $(this).closest('tr');
      var input_valueLat = linha.find('[name="latMap"]').val();
      var input_valueMap = linha.find('[name="lngMap"]').val();
      $(window.opener.document)
      .find('#latMap')
      .val(input_valueLat);
      $(window.opener.document)
      .find('#lngMap')
      .val(input_valueMap);
   });
});
```

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou do jeito que eu queria! uma dúvida por fora, não sou muito experiente com javascript, mas eu consigo fazer esse mesmo botão executar a função de outro do x.php? Pois no caso eu já consigo enviar os valores para o input de lá, e se fizer executar a mesma função de lá (no caso ele usa o valor dos inputs do x.php para marcar em um mapa) ficará melhor ainda, mas muito obrigado!

Comment: Nãi sei se entendi direito, vc quer que esse botão da janela aberta chame insira os valores no input e chame uma função na janela que abriu?

Comment: Já consegui fazer, coloquei um window.opener.document.getElementById('localizar').click(); logo abaixo da última linha do script que você fez. Uma dúvida é que tem como ele focar de volta para a pagina x? algo como window.opener.focus()?

Comment: Entendi, só que estranho que ele foca no navegador mas abre uma guia about:blank, não volta para a mesma janela parent

Comment: Aaaah, identifiquei o erro, não estava colocando dentro do script que abre o window.open, agora tudo certo, ví que só funciona no chrome mesmo, tanto no firefox quanto o explorer (um não foca e outro abre uma nova janela window.open). Mas disso eu já sabia, novamente, muito obrigado pelas respostas, tudo perfeito!